# Entity Framework 6 - using a class with three tables (Db first)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm, mapping

I'm working with Entity Framework 6.

I have three tables in my database:

- Payments
- Payments_temp
- Payments_error

`Payments` has these columns:

- Id
- Amount
- Json

The other two tables have the same columns, but with a column called Result.

Can I create a class `Payment` with all columns and then mapping in the database just the properties I need from a case?

Example:

```
public class Payment
{
    public string id {get;set;}
    public decimal amount {get;set;}
    public string json {get;set;}
    public string result {get;set;}
}
```

And in `DbContext`:

```
Using(var context = new dbcontext())
{
     paym = new Payment();
     context.Payments.add(paym);

     paym.result = "OK";
     context.Payments_temp.add(paym);
     context.Payments_error.add(paym);
}
```

If someone knows how do that, I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Are you doing code-first or database-first?

Comment: im using database-first

Comment: I doubt that it will work that way since DB first will generate the class with the name of the table. So it will create 3 classes in your case

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Convert the clases with json serialize.

In DBContext

```
  {
     paym = new Payments();
     context.Payments.add(paym);
     paym.result = "OK";
     var serializedPayments = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paym);
     context.Payments_temp
             .add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payments_temp>(paym));
     context.Payments_error
             .add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payments_error>(paym));
}
```

Comment: `paym = new BasePayment();` and `(Payments_temp)paym)` doesn´t throw an InvalidCastException??